# Prove, that relation $R(G,\preccurlyeq_G) \; (G_1 \preccurlyeq_G G_2: G_1 \text{ is subgraph of } G_2)$ is a Poset

Tags: graph-theory, relations, order-theory

I'm currently studying for my exams and want to know if my proof of the following task is done correctly:

> Prove, that the relation $R(G,\preccurlyeq_G) \; (G_1 \preccurlyeq_G G_2 \Leftrightarrow G_1 \text{is a subgraph of } G_2)$ of two graphs (unsigned, labeled) is a partial ordered set (Poset).

---

Poset$\implies$ Relation must be reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive.

**Reflexive:**

Let $G=(V,E): V=\text{Vertices},\quad E= \text{Edges}$

$(G_1,G_1)\Longleftrightarrow \text{Every graph is a subgraph of itself.}$
That means, that $(G_1\preccurlyeq_G G_1)\Longleftrightarrow V_1$ is a subset of $V_2 $ and $ E_1$ is a subset of $ E_2$

**Antisymmetric:**

$(G_1 \preccurlyeq_G G_2)$ and $(G_2 \preccurlyeq_G G_1) \implies G_1 = G_2$
$\Longleftrightarrow (V_1$ is a subset of $ V_2$ and $ E_1$ is a subset of $ E_2)$ and $(V_2$ is a subset of $ V_1$ and $ E_2$ is a subset of $ E_1)\implies G_1=G_2 \text{ because }V_1$ is a subset of $ V_2 $ and $ V_2$ is a subset of $ V_1 \implies V_1 = V_2$ (Analogous to $E$)

**Transitive:**

$(G_1 \preccurlyeq_G G_2)$ and $(G_2 \preccurlyeq_G G_3) \implies (G_1 \preccurlyeq_G G_3)$
$\Longleftrightarrow (V_1 $ is a subset of $ V_2 $ and $ E_1 $ is a subset of $ E_2) $and$ (V_2 $ is a subset of $ V_3 $ and $ E_2 $ is a subset of $ E_3) \implies (V_1 $ is a subset of $ V_3 $ and $ E_1 $ is a subset of $ E_3)$

If $V_1 $ is a subset of $ V_2$ and $E_1 $ is a subset of $ E_2$ would be the same as: $|V_1| \leq |V_2|$ and $ |E_1| \leq |E_2|$
Because $V_2 $ is a subset of $ V_3$ and $E_2 $ is a subset of $ E_3$ would be the same as: $|V_2| \leq |V_3|$ and $|E_2| \leq |E_3|$ is
$V_1 $ is a subset of $ V_3$ and $E_1 $ is a subset of $ E_3  
\Longleftrightarrow |V_1| \leq |V_3| $ and $ |E_1| \leq |E_3|$
and that's why $(G_1 \preccurlyeq_G G_3).$

$\implies R(G,\preccurlyeq_G)$ is a $\textit{Poset}$

Kind regards,
Doesbaddel

Comment: Hi, welcome.  Logically, your proof looks sound.  Notationally, it's a little dense.  I would suggest writing out your sentences in English.  Replace $\wedge$ with “and”, etc.  Also, $\sim$ is a weird choice of symbol for a partial ordering.  I've seen it more often used for equivalence relation.  But that's not your choice, I know.

Comment: For instance, “$(G_1 \sim G_2)\in R \wedge (G_2 \sim G_3)\in R \implies (G_1 \sim G_3) \in R$” can simply be written as “Suppose $G_1 \sim G_2$ and $G_2 \sim G_3$.  We wish to show that $G_1 \sim G_3$.”

Comment: Thank you! Alright, I will try to do that. Yeah you're right. We actually used this symbol: $(\preccurlyeq_G); \;R(G, \preccurlyeq_G) $, but I was too lazy to type it out everytime/copy-paste it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The notation '$(G_1\sim G_2)\in R$' seems superfluous. Either use $\sim$ or $R$ for the relation, e.g. saying that the *pair* $(G_1,G_2)\,\in R$ abbreviated as $G_1\,R\,G_2$, or use $G_1\sim G_2$.

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Is it good now?

Comment: @Berci what do you think?

Comment: I've changed the relation-symbol; replaced most of the mathematical symbols with actual words and changed the layout. Is everything right now?

Comment: I don't think the relation you have written is a **set** in the first place, unless you have an invisible assumption that vertex names are drawn from some particular known set. What does $G$ in $(G,\preccurlyeq_G)$ mean?

Comment: @HenningMakholm It means that the Relation "$\preccurlyeq_G$" is applied to Graphs $(G_1, G_2, \dots ,G_n)$

Comment: @Doesbaddel: No, what does the letter $G$ before the comma mean?

Comment: And in any case, if $\preccurlyeq_G$ can be applied to _any_ graphs, then it is not a set at all. There are too many graphs to make a set.

Comment: That should be the Graph "G" I guess. Is this mathematically wrong?

Comment: You're right, it can only be applied to those who follow the rules of the given relation then.

Comment: @Doesbaddel: Please define which graphs those are. You have not disclosed any restrictions of which graphs you're consdering yet.

Comment: In the task, there was only given that it needs to be a graph that is unsigned and labeled. The thing is, this exercise was given in the pre-exam and therefore was typed out by a friend of mine after the exam. There are possibilities, that he forgot something or mixed it up. :/ That's why there might be some mistakes.

Comment: The annotation is similar to the annotation of fields in algebra, but I'm not sure if this is correctly typed out.